# Format HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to format HTML.. I have tried using `tidymanaged` like

```
<html>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/lib/styles/default/general_app.css'></link>
<title>test</title>
<body>asd<input type='text' />
</body>
</html>
```

**TIDYMANAGED**

```
using (Document doc = Document.FromString(newFile))
                {
                    doc.ShowWarnings = false;
                    doc.Quiet = true;
                    doc.DocType = TidyManaged.DocTypeMode.Strict;
                    doc.DropFontTags = true;
                    doc.UseLogicalEmphasis = true;
                    doc.OutputXhtml = false;
                    doc.OutputXml = false;
                    doc.MakeClean = true;
                    doc.DropEmptyParagraphs = true;
                    doc.CleanWord2000 = true;
                    doc.QuoteAmpersands = true;
                    doc.JoinStyles = false;
                    doc.JoinClasses = false;
                    doc.Markup = true;
                    doc.IndentSpaces = 4;
                    doc.IndentBlockElements = TidyManaged.AutoBool.Yes;
                    doc.CharacterEncoding = TidyManaged.EncodingType.Utf8;
                    doc.CleanAndRepair();
                    parsed = doc.Save();
                }
```

but it removed slash from input tag and shows link tag like `<link />` where I want `

Then I tried `prettydiff` that is http://prettydiff.com/

```
var str = "<html><body><h1>hello</h1></body><html>";

// Options can be viewed at:
// http://prettydiff.com/documentation.xhtml#function_properties

var options = {
  source: str,
  mode: "beautify", //  beautify, diff, minify, parse
  lang: "html",
  wrap: 100,
  inchar: "\t", // indent character
  insize: 1 // number of indent characters per indent
}

var pd = prettydiff(options); // returns and array: [beautified, report]

var pretty = pd[0];
console.log(pretty);
var report = pd[1];


console.log(report);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/28rgu51x/4/)

but it doesn't work even..can someone give me some suggesion please how to solve it?

Comment: Take a look at developer console in jsFiddle, there are errors telling you that you cant load external .js over "http" protocol. Simply change the link adress of external resources from `http://examle.com` to `https://example.com`

Comment: @Buksy updated question..`https://` didn't solve problem so I add it to javascript directly..please check and tell me suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't met prettydiff dependencies, take a look at example in [index.xhtml in prettydiff github repository](https://github.com/prettydiff/prettydiff/blob/master/index.xhtml#L2131). There are multiple libraries/scripts you need to include before prettydiff.

```
<script src="lib/finalFile.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/safeSort.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="ace/ace.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="api/dom.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/csspretty.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/csvpretty.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/diffview.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/jspretty.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/markuppretty.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="prettydiff.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you required prettydiff module? On GitHub they ask you to require it like this:

```
var prettydiff = require("prettydiff"),
args       = {
    source: "asdf",
    diff  : "asdd",
    lang  : "text"
},
output     = prettydiff.api(args);
```

Check the whole starting guide at https://github.com/prettydiff/prettydiff/

Comment: I want to run from javascript..I had written `var global = {},
  args = {
    source: "asdf",
    diff: "asdd",
    lang: "text"
  },
  output = prettydiff(args);` already..still not working